# Swagger: Failed to load API definition when POST and PUT in same controller (Web Api core)

Tags: asp.net, swagger, swashbuckle

Swagger page is not loading when I have POST and PUT method in the same API controller. If I remove or comment either one from the controller it is working fine.

Is there any way to use both in the same controller.

[Swagger page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLEC1.png)

Below is my code snippets,

### Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Activity>>> List()
    {
        return await _mediator.Send(new List.Query());
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Activity>> Details(Guid id)
    {
        return await _mediator.Send(new Details.Query { Id = id });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Unit>> Create(Create.Command command)
    {
        return await _mediator.Send(command);
    }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Unit>> Edit(Guid id, Edit.Command command)
    {
        command.Id = id;
        return await _mediator.Send(command);
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Unit>> Remove(Guid id)
    {
        return await _mediator.Send(new Remove.Command { Id = id });
    }
```

### Swagger configure in Startup

```
//Included swagger
        services.AddSwaggerGen(options => options.SwaggerDoc(name: "v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Reactivities", Version = "v1" }));
```

// Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
app.UseSwagger();

```
        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(x => { x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Reactivities - V1"); });
```

Am I missing something? Please advice.

Comment: have a look at this link https://codegodigital.com/dotnet/failed-to-load-api-definition-fetch-error-undefined-swagger-v1-swagger-json/